# ¿Cómo quitar de la URL el public_html al hacer deploy en un hosting compartido?

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

He puesto en produccion mi sitio web hecho en laravel 8, lo he subido mediante FTP y en la raiz he creado dos carpetas una llamada como biblioteca y la otra como public_html en esta ultima guarde todo lo que estaba dentro de mi carpeta public y en la carpeta biblioteca guarde todo lo restante.

El problema esta que para acceder a mi sitio tengo que colocar

> [www.biblioteca.example.com/public_html/login](http://www.biblioteca.example.com/public_html/login)

y quiero que quede como

> [www.biblioteca.example.com/login](http://www.biblioteca.example.com/login)

Ya he tratado de varias maneras pero ninguna me ha servido y he visto que hay inseguras como copiar el `index.php` y `htaccess` en este caso a la carpeta biblioteca.

Creo que la mas segura es crear otro `htaccess` en la carpeta biblioteca y redireccionar con el siguiente código

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

PD: El sitio funciona bien pero tengo que colocar el public_html en la URL.

Comment: todo lo que tienes en la carpeta public_html cópialo a la ruta superior

Comment: Pero eso es un problema de seguridad

Comment: No entiendo porque lo ves como un problema de seguridad, Los hostings, VPS, (...), tienen la ruta publica la cual son archivos css, js, img, html, txt. ... y demás, que son accesibles por todos. Los contenidos sensibles se guardan una ruta antes de la raíz del dominio, por lo que no es accesible desde la url. y cuentas con un directorio (storage) en la cual guardas imágenes de usuarios y la virtualizas a la raíz principal, la cual solo será de lectura. el htacces no es seguro para proteger rutas críticas, pero si para la estructura del directorio.

Comment: si sacas el htacces queda expuesto el .env según tengo entendido

Comment: además si tienes contenidos sensibles en el directorio public entonces tienes un error de estructura, y te recomiendo que reorganices el proyecto

Comment: No hay nada sensible en public, pero tu me dices que saque lo de public y lo pegue en la raíz entonces estaría revirtiendo la seguridad de laravel.

Comment: Si te queda expuesto él .env es porque estas guardando la información en la raíz del proyecto y no un directorio antes de este.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130041/discussion-between-roldos-and-kevinrueda).

Comment: Mira en la raiz tengo dos carpetas /biblioteca y /public_html, me dices que saque lo de /public_html y lo pegue en / o /biblioteca?